# Cambiar los valores de slider y refrescar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Estoy tratando de crear un barra de rangos  dinámica que cambie de valor al hacer `click` en un botón ,

```
var slider1 = new Slider("#ex1");  
slider1.options.min = 20;
slider1.setValue(50);
slider1.slider('refresh');

<input id="ex1" data-slider-id='ex1Slider' data-slider-ticks="[10,100]"   data-slider-ticks-labels="[ 10,80]"    type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="30" data-slider-enabled="false" />
```

Pero se duplica en lugar de refrescar [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: alguna idea porfa?

Comment: buenas hay alguien que me pueda orientar ?

Comment: En tu ejemplo solo hay una barra, ¿podrías [edit] tu pregunta y mostrar como agregas las otras dos?

Comment: @eduardo-palomino nos falta código para poder ayudar, que librerías usas? donde esta dicho `boton` ? donde esta el codigo de javascript del boton??? .... Edita la pregunta y danos mas datos!!

Answer (score 0):

si usas `jQuery UI slider` esta mal el código que nos das.

```
$(function() { 
    var $slide = $("#something").slider({
        range: true,
        values: [25, 75],
        min: 0,
        max: 100
    });
    $slide.slider("option", "min", 25); // Colocado estatico
    $slide.slider("value", $slide.slider("value")); // forzamos el refreco 
});
```